# Save data in database automatically at particular time

Tags: java, database

I want to save data in database automatically at particular time.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con = DriverManager.
    getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regression","root", "root");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
int i = stmt.executeUpdate("
    insert into Severity(blocking,Critical,Normal,Small,Enhancement)
    values('"+Blocking+"','"+Critical+"','"+Normal+"','"+small+"','"+Enhancement+"')");
```

In android there is a method timer where we can set the time and at that time it will trigger. Is there is any method in java where we can trigeer at particular time ???

Comment: create a thread, that will endlessly check the time using Date class, and when a particular time comes then it will call that method code.

Comment: You can use a [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Calculate the delay until the save date (using `Calendar`) and `.schedule()` your `Runnable`, which will save the data.

You will probably want to use a [`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29).

Side note: **please** use a prepared statement and not string concatenation to generate your SQL query! The JDK has [all it takes to do so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), there is no reason not to use it.